# Is there an application frontpage before the permission page?

Tags: facebook, localization, permissions, frontpage

I have developed an application that can be used in several languages.
The permission page displayed the name and basic headline of the application in one and unique language (+ the permissions list). I didn't find any options that would allow me to translate this page in different language: I'm talking about the headline, description here.

So I was wondering if there is any way I could display a 'frontpage' before the permission page, showcasing the application (in the current user locale) with a link going to the permission page (where the user will install the application) ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can grab the locale from the browser's request. See: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-accept-lang-locales

And if you determine that the user is not already logged in, then before you display a login link, post up the language specific content that each have a login link.